# Using \pgfkeys in \section

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, pgfkeys

I am using `\pgfkeys` to help organize custom symbols.
However, I ran into a problem when trying to execute a key inside `\section` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{a-key/.code={a-value}}
\begin{document}
    Test \pgfkeys{a-key}
    \section{\pgfkeys{a-key} section} % <- doesn't work
\end{document}
```

In this example, my `pdflatex` just freeze while compiling without giving error message. Have I done something wrong? Is executing a `\pgfkeys` possible in `\section`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\protect`ing gets things back on track.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{a-key/.code={a-value}}
\begin{document}
    Test \pgfkeys{a-key}
    \section{\protect\pgfkeys{a-key} section} % <-  works
\end{document}
```

[image]