# Using pgfkeys inside overlay specification

Tags: beamer, overlays, pgfkeys

I would like to use labels to assign overlay specifications. Below is the code I have so far. My main question is why does not the following  terminate to compile.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/.unknown/.code=%
        {\PackageError{some name}{Label \pgfkeyscurrentname{} not defined}{}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}        
        \pgfkeys{/bar 1/.append={2}}
        \pgfkeys{/foo 2/.append={1}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<\pgfkeys{/bar 1}> Some bar
            \item<\pgfkeys{/foo 2}> and foo
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**My solution so far:**

The following code fixes the issue above. However, when I write one of the labels in the overlay specification wrong pdflatex does not terminate, as the key is unknown. That means, the `.unknown` handler is ignored, which is why I am not satisfied with my solution..

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/.unknown/.code=%
    {\PackageError{some name}{Label \pgfkeyscurrentname{} not defined}{}}%
}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{Title}        
        \pgfkeys{/bar 1/.append={2}}
        \pgfkeys{/foo 2/.append={1}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<\pgfkeysvalueof{/bar 1}> Some bar
            \item<\pgfkeysvalueof{/foo 2}> and foo
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Related Questions:**

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238667/expansion-of-overlay-specification-macro) it was suggested to just redefine `\item`. However, I am not sure how to redefine the overlay macros in a good and general way. With my current approach I can use the label approach with all overlay aware commands.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230445/relative-order-of-overlays-in-beamer) I asked about this the first time. I got it working without `pgfkeys`, storing the values in macros. But then I can only use letters in labels, which is inconvenient.

Here it was suggest to [protect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152382/using-pgfkeys-in-section) the `pgfkeys` command with `\protect` but that did not work. Thought it is related as the resulting problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first code with

```
\item<\pgfkeys{/bar 1}> Some bar
\item<\pgfkeys{/foo 2}> and foo
```

won't work because `\pgfkeys` is the command to process keys, it does not return the value of the keys given – what's beamer supposed to do with `\pgfkeys{/bar 1, /foo 2, tikz/draw=green}`?

If you need the value stored in a key, use `\pgfkeysvalueof` as you did in your second example. However, when a non-existing key is used `\pgfkeysvalueof` will expand to `\relax` which will break Beamer's `<…>` parser.

I don't see a way to insert an error message here (this will still mess with Beamer) but you can default to an overlay specification of `1-` instead.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\newcommand\pgfkeysValueof[1]{%
  \csname\ifcsname pgfk@#1\endcsname pgfk@#1\else pgfkeysValueofDefault\fi\endcsname}
\newcommand*\pgfkeysValueofDefault{1-}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}        
\pgfkeys{/bar 1/.append={2}}
\pgfkeys{/foo 2/.append={1}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<\pgfkeysValueof{/bar 1}> Some bar
    \item<\pgfkeysValueof{/foo 2}> and foo
    \item<\pgfkeysValueof{/foobar}> I'm wrong
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```