# confusion in edef, def, and expandafter

Tags: macros

Yesterday, I provided an (incorrect) answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663740/alternative-to-edef-c-pgfkeys-a/663743#663743), and would like to check my understanding of why it was wrong.

The answer I provided produced (almost) the correct result in the output document, but for very wrong reasons, and I would like a deeper understanding of what my answer is actually doing (as opposed to what I thought it was doing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \pgfkeys{/a/.code=(a)}
  \pgfkeys{/a}
  \def\b{\pgfkeys{/a}}
  \b
  \expandafter\def\c{\pgfkeys{/a}}
  \c
\end{document}
```

seems to produce the correct output of `(a) (a) (a)` (with an additional space between the first and second `(a)`). I didn't use `\show` to see what each of `\a`, `\b`, and `\c` were, though, so didn't actually answer the question as asked.

I assumed that `\expandafter\def\c{\pgfkeys{/a}}` would expand the `pgfkeys` part, and assign it to `\c`, and so do what the original questioner wanted.

From @DavidCarlisle's comment, this *only* works because `\c` is already defined, and so this re-defines the expansion of `\c` (in the comment `\T1-cmd`, in my case `\OT1-cmd`) to be `\pgfkeys{/a}` (not expanded), and so is the same as `\b`. The use of `\c` then expands, and produces the same as the expansion of `\b` (additionally, breaking any use of accents at any point further in the document).

Is my understanding of what went wrong correct? If not, what does this actually *do*? Bonus question: is there a number of `\expandafter` here that would make this actually work the way I thought?

Comment: \expandafter always jumps over one token, so to get at the \pgfkeys you would need `\expandafter\def\expandafter\c\expandafter{\pgfkeys{/a}}`. But it only expand once, it doesn't expand fully. So \c would then have the definition `\expandafter \pgfkeys@@set \expandafter {\pgfkeysdefaultpath }{/a}`

Comment: a side note: I believe the culprit with some difficulties involving \expandafter is that we tend to see `{` and `}` as "mere group delimiters that don't really count", but TeX sees each one of them as one token (unless the standard plain/LaTeX catcodes have been changed), so they do count for `\expandafter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\expandafter\def\tmp{abc}`

- would expand `\tmp` so give an undefined command error in most cases.

  (In your example this expanded the accent command `\c` which     avoided a error but produced a totally unwanted result as shown below)
- If `\tmp` was defined via `\def\tmp{x}` the above would be

  `\def x{abc}`

  and give an error that there was a missing command as you can not define `x`
- If `\tmp` was defined via `\def\tmp{\y{x}}` the above would be

  `\def\y{x}{abc}`

  so it would define `\y` to be `x` and typeset `abc`.
- If `\tmp` was defined via `\def\tmp{\xxa\xxb\xxc}` (your case, with internals of the accent mechanism) the above would be

  `\def\xxa\xxb\xxc{abc}`

  which would define `\xxa` to be a macro that must be followed by `\xxb\xxc` and if so expands to `abc`

  So this would break most uses of `\xxa` but

  `\tmp` has not been redefined so `\tmp` expands to `\xxa\xxb\xxc` as before which now expands to `abc`  which is why your final `\c` appeared to produce the intended output even though `\c` had not been redefined.

---

Answer to the bonus question is no, no `\expandafter` will work.

If `\def\qqq{x}`  you can fully expand `\qqq` in one step then

`\expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\qqq}`

is essentially what you intended and is

`\def\tmp{x}`

so does define `\tmp`.

However `\pgfkeys` is not expandable it does many assignments so you can not force a final value by applying `\expandafter`.